# Use external files based on os from junit test when building with hudson/jenkins?

Tags: junit, hudson, development-environment, jenkins

In a maven project I have some junit tests where I need to refer to some runtime libraries (the birt runtime) when running the tests:

```java
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    // init osgi/birt rte.
    BEngine.getEngine().init("C:\\birt-runtime-2_6_1\\ReportEngine\\");
  }

  @Test
  public void testname() {
       // run test that requires the initialization of the above rte.
  }
```

This works fine when running the tests locally from eclipse. My maven project is also build on a linux server running jenkins but currently I disable tests that requires the above runtime libs.

I am considering to copy the runtime libs to the server running hudson and see if I can get hudson to pick up the location of these files when the tests are executed on hudson.

But to do this I need to use the correct location of the rte in the tests.

Any suggestions for doing this? Eg using env variables that can both be understood on windows/linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values will not change during the lifetime of the test run (i.e. the build), then use an environmental variable, and just set it as an option in the [surefire plugin, systemPropertyVariables](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables).

The correct way to do this for different environments is to use different [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in maven.

You can have a default profile which includes the set of variables for windows, and another for the hudson.

EDIT: For running the tests correctly from within Eclipse, then simply you can have a default value for the variable

```
public String getRteLocation() {
    String s = System.getProperty("test.rte.location");
    return (s == null) ? "C:\\birt-runtime-2_6_1\\ReportEngine\\" : s;
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    // init osgi/birt rte.
    BEngine.getEngine().init(getRteLocation());
 }
```

or simply set the environment variable in the Run Configuration in Eclipse.

EDIT: Just a clarification, when I say environment variables, I mean the -D variables set from the java command line.

Comment: I use maven profiles for some of my other projects but will that not only work when building with maven? I still want to be able to run the tests from inside eclipse using run-as-junit-test so. How will the eclipse test/run configuration framework know that it should use the env vars. specified in a hudson profile in a pom file?

Comment: Added more text for running from within Eclipse.

Comment: Would defining the env. var "test.rte.location" on the server not be enough? I don't see why I need a profile for this.

Comment: @tul certainly. You can do it that way. If you do it in a profile, then it's all in the POM rather than server configuration, but defininng the env var would work as well.

Comment: Good point. But from the build profile documentation I don't see how you can set an env. variable that can be read in the test using 'System.getProperty("test.rte.location")'. Its possible to specify properties but how is it possible to create an env. var in a profile?

Comment: Note that when I say env. var, I mean something that could be passed in via -D, not a real env var. Sorry, that was slightly confusing. In a profile, you can set <properties> which can then be substitued elsewhere, for instance in the parameters to the surefire plugin.